# Need a regex expression for ng-pattern which should be floating point and always greater than 0 but should not allow 0

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

Allowed numbers: 0.1, 0.2, 10.1, up to 99.9 max.

Not allowed: 0, 123, 12.23.

Using

```
/^(?!(0))+[0-9]{1,2}(\.\d{1})?$/g
/^(0*[1-9]?\.?[0-9]?)$/g
```

Code:

```
<form name="formName" class="weightChk">
 <input name="weightChecker" type="number" ng-model="vm.ItemsWeight" 
   class="form-control" ng-show="vm.saveManifestButton" style="width:50%;"ng-pattern="/^(?!(0))[0-9]{1,2}(\.\d{1})?$/"/>
 <label style="color:#6d6c6c;margin-top:2px;" >Weight (Kg)</label>
 <span class="error " ng-show="formName.weightChecker.$invalid">Enter correct weight</span>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you explain why 12.23 is not allowed, it seems to fit your criteria?

Comment: @phuzi there's one `.` at end of `12.23.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check for value greater than 0 and than test with following regex for remaining rules

```
^0*\d{1,2}(?:\.\d+)?$
```

---

```js
const regex = /^0*\d{1,2}(?:\.\d+)?$/gm;
const strs = ['0','123','123.123','12.12','220','22.22','22.3','011.2',
'10','0.0']

strs.forEach(str=>{
  console.log(str, str > 0 && regex.test(str))
})
```

Comment: @Sourabh a simple and better approach here we can follow is `str > 0`  and than use `^0*\d{1,2}(?:\.\d+)?$` to test valid string

Comment: @Thefourthbird no the `12.23` is valid match, the one OP had as invalid match is having `.` at the end, i.e. `12.23.`

Answer (score 0):

A simple way could be to match a digit with an optional decimal part and check if the value is greater than zero and smaller than 100.

```
const pattern = /^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/;
const s = "0.0";
let result = pattern.test(s) && s > 0 && s < 100;
```

```js
const pattern = /^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/;
[
  "0.1",
  "0.2",
  "10.1",
  "99.9",
  "1.1",
  "1.0",
  "10",
  "12.23",
  "100",
  "100.1",
  "100.0",
  "200",
  "200.6",
  "0.0",
  "0.",
  "123",
  "0"
].forEach(s => {
  console.log(s + " ==> " + (pattern.test(s) && s > 0 && s < 100))
});
```

If you want to use a regex, you could use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to match either 0.1 - 0.9 or match 1 - 99.9

```
^(?:[0-9]\.[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]?(?:\.[0-9])?)$
```

*About the pattern*

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[0-9]\.[1-9]` Match 0-9 followed by a dot and 1-9 to not match 0.0
  - `|` Or
  - `[1-9][0-9]?` Match 1-9, optionally 0-9
  - `(?:\.[0-9])?` Optionally match a dot and 0-9
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FTnVDR/1)

```js
const pattern = /^(?:[0-9]\.[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]?(?:\.[0-9])?)$/;
[
  "0.1",
  "0.2",
  "10.1",
  "99.9",
  "1.1",
  "1.0",
  "10",
  "100",
  "100.1",
  "100.0",
  "200",
  "200.6",
  "0.0",
  "0.",
  "123",
  "12.23",
  "0"
].forEach(s => console.log(s + " ==> " + pattern.test(s)));
```

If you want to allow leading zeroes and there can be more than 1 digit after the dot, prepend the pattern with `0*` and match 1+ digits `\.[0-9]+`

```
^0*(?:[0-9]\.[1-9][0-9]*|[1-9][0-9]?(?:\.[0-9]+)?)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KaWe26/1)

```js
const pattern = /^0*(?:[0-9]\.[1-9][0-9]*|[1-9][0-9]?(?:\.[0-9]+)?)$/;
[
  "0.1",
  "0.2",
  "10.1",
  "99.9",
  "1.1",
  "1.0",
  "0.20000",
  "10",
  "12.23",
  "100",
  "100.1",
  "100.0",
  "200",
  "200.6",
  "0.0",
  "0.",
  "123",
  "0"
].forEach(s => console.log(s + " ==> " + pattern.test(s)));
```

Comment: 2 digit should also be true. 10 12 13 something like this also accept. the only thing that it should not accept is 0 it should accept all the numbers  between 0 to 99.9 only

Comment: @Sourabh Then you could make the dot part optional `^(?:[0-9]\.[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]?(?:\.[0-9])?)$` See https://regex101.com/r/BqGUMg/1 I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const regex = /^[1-9]|\d{2}\.\d{1}$/

const nums = [0.1, 0.2, 0.0, 10.1, 99.9,  0, 123, 12.23];

nums.forEach(el => {
  if (regex.test(el))
    console.log(el + " is a match!")
  else
    console.log(el + " is not a match!")
})
```